# How to rename GIT central repository

Tags: git

We have a central GIT repository in our organization. I would like to know what is the best way to rename this central repository.

Thanks!

Comment: Once you do that, you will need to point all of your distributed repos to the new origin.  Use `git remote set-url origin <new-url>`

Comment: Thank you ! I did not think it was that simple. So, just use the mv command and change the repo name on the central server, and let the users reference the new repo name when they do a clone? Do we need to edit .git/config?

Comment: You might consider making a symbolic link, so users don't have to *immediately* update everything: `mv old-name new-name ; ln -s new-name old-name`. You can delete the old name (now just a symlink, so you can use `rm old-name`) once everyone in the organization has updated to the new name.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the name of a repo depends on how said repository is managed.

- On GitHub (or BitBucket, or...), you would the the repo name through GitHub GUI admin page for that repo.
- On a server managed by http, you would simply change the name of the root directory But you would also have to modify the `httpd.conf` in order to reference that new path.
  And you could duplicate that entry, if you don't want the users to be *immediately* impacted.
  A symlink wouldn't be enough.
- On a server managed by ssh, simply renaming the directory is enough.

In any cases, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242559/how-to-rename-git-central-repository#comment18042864_13242559) [slashingweapon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292052/slashingweapon), you need each user to change their remote url (as described in "[Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url)")

```
git remote set-url origin new-url
```